# Polymer pass data of app-route to custom element gone undefined

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to pass parameter of app-route to custom element gone undefined. I can display that parameter in file but in custom element, it gone undefined. Following is my code and please help me to check how to fix it. Thanks.

In custom element file, `getid` gone undefined.

My File

```
<app-route
    route="[[route]]"
    pattern="/:slug/:id"
    data="{{routeData}}"></app-route>

    <!-- display correctly -->
    [[routeData.id]]

<myelement-http-get
    id="getCategoryData"
    getid="[[routeData.id]]"
    geturl="http://localhost:9000/polymer/category/"
    jsonobject="{{jsonobject}}"
    failure="{{failure}}"></myelement-http-get>
```

Custom element

```
<script>
  Polymer({
      is: 'myelement-http-get',

      properties: {
        geturl: String,

        getid: String,

        jsonobject: {
          type: Object,
          notify: true
        },

        failure: {
          type: Boolean,
          notify: true,
          readOnly: true
        }

      },

      ready: function () {
        /* undefined found this.getid */
        this.$.ajaxData.url = this.geturl + this.getid;
        this.$.ajaxData.generateRequest();
      },

      handleResponse: function (data) {
        this.jsonobject = data.detail.response;
      }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data binding effects for `getid` and `geturl` happen *after* the `ready` callback, so that's not where you'd want to manipulate those properties.

Instead, you should use a [complex observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#complex-observers) to observe `getid` and `geturl`. This observer would only be called when both properties are defined and changed (this behavior changes slightly in Polymer 2.0).

You should remove the changes from `ready`, and add the complex observer like shown here:

```
Polymer({
  ...

  properties: { ... },

  observers: ['_generateRequest(geturl, getid)'],

  _generateRequest: function(geturl, getid) {
    if (geturl && getid) {
      this.$.ajaxData.url = geturl + getid;
      this.$.ajaxData.generateRequest();
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: thanks, it's partially correct. but `observers: ['_generateRequest(geturl, getid)'],` cannot update when I got third page. `geturl` always display second page URL.